# 10-15 Second Keyboard Unrecognized Issue

Tags: boot, kernel, keyboard

A family member bought a new laptop ([HP Pavilion 15-eg0073cl](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06956721)) and asked me if I could put Ubuntu on it. I installed 20.04.2 this weekend and have noticed that the keyboard doesn't accept any input on the login screen for about 10-15 seconds (sometimes more) after a cold boot. After that time, I'm able to use the keyboard just fine. Issue also manifests when activating the lock screen and waiting for a minute or two. After waiting for 10-15 seconds, the keyboard is recognized again and behaves normally.

I installed the "Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer" application and tried the 5.11.6-051106-generic kernel (newest one available at the moment) just to see if that would help fix the issue (p.s. Secure Boot has been turned off). The behavior of the issue is still the same. It's worth noting that there is no delay if I plug in a USB keyboard and boot like outlined above in case this is useful information.

I hesitate pasting all 500+ lines of output from lshw and I'm not sure what information would be helpful to share from that. I installed and ran hwinfo. Here's a section from that output that I think might give some more info on the keyboard:

```
52: PS/2 00.0: 10800 Keyboard
  [Created at input.226]
  Unique ID: 6E9_.+49ps10DtUF
  Hardware Class: keyboard
  Model: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
  Vendor: 0x0001 
  Device: 0x0001 "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
  Compatible to: int 0x0211 0x0001
  Device File: /dev/input/event9
  Device Files: /dev/input/event9, /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd
  Device Number: char 13:73
  Driver Info #0:
    XkbRules: xfree86
    XkbModel: pc104
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

I appreciate any thoughts you all might have in advance. Thank you! :)

EDIT: I installed the 5.13.0 kernel last night and the issue still seems to persist. I'll keep updating kernels as they release.

Comment: I have the same problem on HP Pavilion 15-eg0016nw 2Q1C0EA (Intel Core i5-1135G7). I tried with a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS, 20.10, 21.04 Beta and Kernel 5.10 and 5.11 (on Ubuntu 20.10). The problem is everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that you've seen the same thing too. I'll update my answer with the version of the kernel that seems to fix the issue (whenever that may be). Hopefully we'll see something here soon! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

So I've got a similar issue with HP 15s-fq2032ua (48V94EA). Keyboard activated with a huge delay (up to ~160s). Pressing some KB keys probably helps to activate it faster.
Luckily I've found a workaround and didn't notice any side effect from it yet

It's a GRUB/boot option

```
i8042.nopnp

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

add option chaging

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"
```

Save with Ctrl+X; then "Y"

```
sudo update-grub
```

Actual result

Before:

```
sudo dmesg | grep i8042
```

...

```
[    0.466661] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
```

...

```
[    26.884289] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input20
```

After:

```
[    2.437169] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input20
```

Comment: Thanks, that made a huge difference on an HP laptop in my household.